# Unable to execute a package in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a package given below:

```
create or replace PACKAGE PKG_CONV_PRODUCT
AS
    PROCEDURE SP_LOAD_DATA;
    PROCEDURE SP_CREATE_BACKUP_TABLES (P_LOADING_ID IN CONV_LOAD_STATS.LOADING_ID%TYPE);
END PKG_CONV_PRODUCT;
```

And package body as below:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY PKG_CONV_PRODUCT
AS
    GV_LOADING_ID PLS_INTEGER;

    TYPE TYP_TABLE_NAME
    IS
        TABLE OF USER_TABLES.TABLE_NAME%TYPE;
        TAB_TABLE_NAME TYP_TABLE_NAME := TYP_TABLE_NAME   ( 'PRODUCTS',
            'PRODUCT_GROUP_CODES',
            'PRODUCT_SUB_GROUPS',
            'PRODUCT_GROUP_CODES_LICENSES',
            'PRODUCTS_OBJECTIVES', 
            'PRODUCTS_HISTORY', 
            'PRODUCTS_BREAK_POINTS', 
            'PRODUCTS_LICENSES', 
            'PRODUCTS_CONCESSION_PERCENT', 
            'PRODUCTS_BD_STATUS') 

    PROCEDURE SP_LOAD_DATA
    IS
    BEGIN
        GV_LOADING_ID := SEQ_CONV_PRODUCT.NEXTVAL;
        SP_CREATE_BACKUP_TABLES (GV_LOADING_ID);
    END SP_LOAD_DATA;

    PROCEDURE SP_CREATE_BACKUP_TABLES(P_LOADING_ID IN CONV_LOAD_STATS.LOADING_ID%TYPE)
    IS
        L_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(50);
    BEGIN
        FOR INDX IN TAB_TABLE_NAME.FIRST .. TAB_TABLE_NAME.LAST
        LOOP
            L_TABLE_NAME := TAB_TABLE_NAME (INDX);
            IF(L_TABLE_NAME = 'PRODUCT_GROUP_CODES_LICENSES')  THEN  
                L_TABLE_NAME :='PROD_GRP_CODES_LICENSES';
            ELSIF(L_TABLE_NAME = 'PRODUCTS_CONCESSION_PERCENT')  THEN  
                L_TABLE_NAME :='PROD_CONCESSION_PERCENT';
            ELSIF(L_TABLE_NAME = 'SPONSORS_ADVISORY_APPROVAL')  THEN  
                L_TABLE_NAME :='SPON_ADVISORY_APPROVAL';
            END IF;

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
                'CREATE TABLE BONUS.' ||
                SUBSTR ('BKP' || 
                P_LOADING_ID || 
                L_TABLE_NAME ,
                1,
                30)|| 
                ' TABLESPACE APP_TABLE AS SELECT * FROM BONUS.' ||
                L_TABLE_NAME ;

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
                'GRANT SELECT ON BONUS.' || 
                SUBSTR ('BKP' || 
                P_LOADING_ID || 
                L_TABLE_NAME ,
                1, 
                30)|| 
                ' TO ROLE_BONUS_SELECT_SR01';
        END LOOP;
    END SP_CREATE_BACKUP_TABLES;
END PKG_CONV_PRODUCT;
```

And i have getting following error:

```
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
ORA-06512: at "BONUS.PKG_CONV_PRODUCT", line 58
ORA-06512: at "BONUS.PKG_CONV_PRODUCT", line 40
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Can you please help me on this?

Comment: What's unclear about "*name is already used by an existing object*"?

Answer (score 0):

This query

```
SELECT *
FROM user_objects
WHERE object_name = 'PKG_CONV_PRODUCT';
```

should tell you what object is already there. Possibly there is a synonym to the same package in a different schema ?

EDIT : Looks like your problem is to do with the CREATE TABLE bonus... statement within your package.

You could add a 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('DROP TABLE BONUS'); line beforehand.

Be aware that will remove any existing data in the BONUS table, and you'll need another source for your CREATE TABLE statement as it currently looks at the BONUS table.

Comment: PKG_CONV_PRODUCT 205320 PACKAGE 05-SEP-13 06-SEP-13 2013-09-06:04:32:50 VALID
PKG_CONV_PRODUCT 205322 PACKAGE BODY 05-SEP-13 06-SEP-13 2013-09-06:04:33:33 VALID